# Android app incompability with Galaxy Pocket

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I'm making an app which have been working with all devices that we tried, but then a user (who wanted our app) had the "Samsung Galaxy Pocket"-phone, and he couldn't find it in Google Play, and when I looked for supported devices in "Android Developer Console" it wasn't supported.

The question is how do I add support for "Samsung Galaxy Pocket".

I removed some of the permissions in android manifest (and a lot of other devices was now on the "white list"), and can't seem to find the problem...

I tried to remove the permissions `"ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"` and `"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` with no success, I also tried to set `"android:hardwareAccelerated"` to false with no success.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
     package="xxx" android:versionName="xxx" android:versionCode="xxx"  
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="xxx" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the same device.
My app require the following functions:

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

and needs the following permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

in an old app i didn't use vibrate that could be the point!